# Reading data from one-to-many relationship SQL table into my model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have below two classes which represent my SQL tables (generated by ADO.net entity data model):

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int Parent_Id { get; set; }
    public string Parent1_Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Parent1_First_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public partial class Student
{
        public int Student_Id { get; set; }
        public string Student_Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Student_First_Name { get; set; }
        public int Parent_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to read the data from my tables in a method as below:

```
var parent = new Parent();
var students = new List<Student>();

using (var dc = new SchoolDataEntities())
{
    students = dc.Students.Where(s => s.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId)).ToList();
    parent = dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId));
    parent.Students = students;     
}
```

I am getting a run-time "Invalid Cast" exception error when I reading from `Parent` table (`Students` table is working fine).

> Error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[SchoolApplication.Parent]' to type 'SchoolApplication.Parent'.'

Someone please educate me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: You need to materialize the query with `dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId)).FirstOrDefault()` or `dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId)).SingleOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is your problem:

```
parent = (Parent)dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId));
```

The output of "Where" is a collection of Parent rather than just a single parent.

You can use "Single" or "First" rather than "Where" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code returns `IQueryable` collection instead of single `Parent` model:

```
parent = dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId));
```

For this reason, you need to materialize the query to `Parent` model with either `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()`:

```
parent = dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId)).FirstOrDefault();

parent = dc.Parents.Where(p => p.Parent_Id.Equals(parentId)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Related: [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[]' using linq lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918272/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbquery1-us)